# How can I copy a folder to another folder with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem

So as the title said, I'm struggling to copy a folder to another folder

I tried this but no results

Edit: I got this to work by fixing the $npath variable I was just giving the url without the folder's name `$npath = $newk->url;`

so the final code will be :

```
    public function copyFolder(Request $request)
{
    $id= $request->get('oldf');
    $new = $request->get('newf');

    $document = Document::find($id);
    $newk = Document::find($new);

    $npath = $newk->url.'/'.$document->nom;

    $file= new Filesystem();

    if($file->copyDirectory($document->url, $npath)){
        return redirect('home');
    }
    return redirect('home');

}
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you verified in your filesystem that the folder isn't actually being copied? You have the same outcome in your function whether the action was successful or not.

Comment: I verified, but nothings happened

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
function recursive_files_copy($source_dir, $destination_dir)
{
    // Open the source folder / directory 
    $dir = opendir($source_dir);

    // Create a destination folder / directory if not exist 
    if (!is_dir($destination_dir)){
        mkdir($destination_dir);
    }
    // Loop through the files in source directory 
    while($file = readdir($dir))
    {
        // Skip . and .. 
        if(($file != '.') && ($file != '..'))
        {
            // Check if it's folder / directory or file 
            if(is_dir($source_dir.'/'.$file))
            {
                // Recursively calling this function for sub directory  
                recursive_files_copy($source_dir.'/'.$file, $destination_dir.'/'.$file);
            }
            else
            {
                // Copying the files
                copy($source_dir.'/'.$file, $destination_dir.'/'.$file);
            }
        }
    }
    
    closedir($dir);
}
```

Comment: `File::copyDirectory` already [copies recursively](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L630).

Comment: should I put it in the Controller or where?

Comment: @Dan I tried also to give the path manually using just "" but no results at all